# What's the opposite of the 'critical hit'?

Tags: terminology

Critical hit means randomly occurring increased damage. *But what's the term for randomly occurring reduced damage?*

My friends said it's a missed hit, but it's not really what I'm looking for.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's why there are random damage rolls.  D&D has a "critical miss", and usually rather bad things happen when it does.  Dumping something like that into a video game is usually the definition of "not fun".

Comment: Why is this question bad?

Comment: There isn't any universal term for this. Different games will have different mechanics and call them different things.

Comment: That doesn't make it a bad question though.

Comment: @fbueckert It's relative, it can be a narrow escape for the opponent...

Comment: "There isn't a universal term for this, but here are some examples in different games" would make a fine answer to this reasonable (IMHO) question. This isn't "too broad".

Comment: @AnnaLear Fine. I stand by my statement that this question is too broad, and kinda dumb, and kinda fitting for the old NARQ, and not really useful and my downvote, but you want a wishy washy non-answer, have a wishy washy non-answer.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz I fail to see how this is too broad. It is very pointedly asking for the opposite of a critical hit. There is only one interpretation of that, especially when they specifically say 'randomly occuring reduced damage'. Your answer is appropriate as there is no direct opposite term. The fact that there is no answer does not automatically make the question broad.

Comment: In D&D, this is called 'critical miss' when you throw a 1 on the dice.

Comment: A glancing blow perhaps? I've seen that come up in a variety of games that randomly occurs and causes reduced damage.

Comment: I've also heard the term "critical failure". Not sure if it's actually used though.

Comment: Is it just me, or should the opening sentence be reworked to something more like "*Randomly occurring increased damage is often referred to as a 'critical hit'.*" Because a critical hit is not necessarily random, in many games a critical hit is the reward for hitting an enemy in a specific place - like a headshot.

Comment: @TrentHawkins Some games do critical hits that way but it is much more prevalent for them to be random.

Comment: That all depends on whether or not the game is based on a dice rolling system and whether or not damage is figured the same way.

Comment: @Ravekner My point is that while a critical hit is nearly always *increased damage*, whether or not this increased damage is random is determined by the game's mechanics. While using a random number generator may be more prevalent, to say "critical hit **means** *random* [...]" is a little disingenuous, no?

Comment: Sorry, guess my response wasn't as clear as I thought it was(typing this out on my phone) I meant that it all depends on how a game registers critical hits, whether it be a dice roll or hitting a specific part of an enemy. The damage portion doesn't necessarily register the same way, some games it is a flat increase in damage of let's say 150% your normal damage. In others, the additional damage done for a critical hit can be randomized by dice rolls (you got a critical so now roll 6 dice instead of 3 to figure out the amount of damage your attack does).

Comment: Critcal misses or what I have seen them listed as in most of the games I play, glancing blows, work along those same parameters for figuring out how much damage you do. It all just depends on what kind of system the game in question uses.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're looking for something that kind of doesn't exist. In terms of a direct opposite to the idea of a 'critical hit', the closest analog would just be to not hit at all, or, y'know, 'miss'. That said, some games include the concept of the 'critical miss' as seen in many tabletop RPGs, or in the earlier Fallout games (for example), which don't just not hit the target, but cause some calamity to the individual making the attack. For instance, you don't just not hit your target, but you shoot yourself in the foot, or your weapon breaks, or whatever.

That said, you've asked about something that isn't really a direct analog, which is when an attack does a reduced amount of damage to a target, even though it hits. This happens in lots of games for lots of reasons and gets called lots of different things. Some games include a concept of 'resistance', wherein  damage is reduced by a set amount, or sometimes, a percentage of the time, by some amount (sometimes fixed, sometimes variable). Others allow for attacks to be blocked, mitigating some of the damage. World of Warcraft has the concept of a 'Glancing Blow', which affects only melee autoattacks, and which causes them to do reduced damage sometimes (and more importantly, a percentage of attacks to be incapable of being critical hits), when attacking opponents of a higher level than yourself.

The point is, there isn't any single term you can throw out there to mean this universally. Some games have mechanics like this. Some don't. They all call them whatever the developer of the given game decides to call them.

Comment: Okay, sometimes there is no answer. At least Googlers will know.

Answer (score 4):

The opposite of a "critical hit" is a so called "Glancing Blow". 
It can occur randomly as the critical hit does and does reduced damage in most games or rule sets.

Answer (score 3):

Lots of other people have given other, valid answers, but no one's mentioned "fumble". Synonymous with "critical miss", you could say it's the opposite of a critical hit. When you fumble, Something Bad will happen such as your weapon jamming or falling out of your hand, or you hit a friend instead, etc...

Comment: I like "critical miss", because that's more or less how it's said in French: "echec critique", so it makes perfect sense to me :p (in one turn-based game I played, a critical miss simply ended your turn)

Comment: In at least tabletop RPG parlance, "Fumble", or "Critical fumble" is more canonical than "critical miss", I agree. Whichever one you Google for, the first page of links are to *fumble* tables. A miss is simply a failure to connect at all with the weapon, not a failure to operate it as expected. So for a reduced damage result, you'd expect a fumble, not a miss.